# How can I compare WebSphere heap dumps?

Tags: java, memory, websphere

I have a series of heap dumps (*.phd files) from WebSphere 6.1.  I suspect a memory leak was occurring in the time period the heap dumps were taken.  I would like to be able to "diff" the two heap dumps (to see which objects were created between the two dumps and are still resident in memory after the later dump).

I've been using IBM's Memory Analyzer (in the IBM Support Assistant) to analyze the heaps, but it doesn't seem to provide this feature.

Comment: I am afraid you cannot do that at least using the IBM tools you mention and eclipse MAT...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eclipse Memory Analyzer, which is included in IBM Support Assistamt as Memory Analyzer, does have a feature to compare two dumps:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/kevgrig/entry/how_to_use_the_memory_analyzer_tool_mat_to_compare_heapdumps_and_system_dumps20?lang=en